# CF autosuggest not working

Tags: coldfusion, autocomplete, coldfusion-8

I am trying to use the cf autosuggest in coldfusion 8.
I have the input as -

```
<cfinput name="tad" 
    autosuggest="(cfc.mywriters(getWriters.authors({cfautosuggestvalue})">
```

My cfc is

```
<cffunction name="getWriters" access="public" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="writers" required="yes"/>
    <cfset myArray = ArrayNew(1)>
    <cftry>
        <cfquery name="getWriters" datasource="mydb">
            SELECT   authors
            FROM     rp_authors
            ORDER BY authors asc
        </cfquery>
        <cfcatch>
            <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
    <cfloop name="getWriters">
        <cfset arrayAppend(myArray,authors)>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn myArray>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: You really need a questions, but for starters, you have 3 open parentheses but only one closing parenthesis in your cfinput.  Also, you start with cfc.mywriters which I assume is the dot path to the CFC, but then you do "(getWriters.authors(..." it should probably cfc.mywriters.getWriters({cfautosuggestvalue}).  Also, your function doesnt actually use your "writers" argument so it will never actually filter anything.  I'd start with getting the path to your CFC/Function correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery to do this. Here is a great example:

http://jacktraynor.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/jquery-autocomplete-using-coldfusion.html

Comment: Thanks! I got it working and now have an off shoot question. I didn't know that my database, inherited from the division, has a free text name column. Yep no last name, first name, middle I, just what ever the person wants to put in. I need to break the text strings on the second comma - A. Smith,John, next name... and thanks for the help I did fix the cfx and my typos!!